# Not allowing user to edit Codeigniter Code

Tags: php, codeigniter

Forgive me if the question looks silly. I was wondering that, when we develop a project in Codeigniter, we give entire source code of it to user and he/she uses it and is also able to make changes in the code.

Since, sometimes he/she don't understand code, some undesirable changes made by user may cause the application generate error or malfunction. In other words, it can be concluded that I am looking for some kind of encryption technique, that will work just as normal PHP code do but will be in encrypted format.

Is there anything, that enables users to use the application, but won't allow him/her to make changes in the code? And the working of application should also remain intact.

Comment: encode your php. there are commercial encoder called `Zend Guard ` from http://www.zend.com.

Comment: Not really. I suppose you could encrypt your source code, but this doesn't always work with frameworks, and won't stop someone from breaking something anyway. It's better to tell your customer which folders they can edit (markup and styles) and which they may not.

Comment: You could supply your source code tarball with your Git folder in it - that will make it very easy to see if someone has tinkered with something they should not have `:)`.

Comment: Beware of possible license issues. I may be wrong but if you use open source code you have to keep it open source (usually)

Comment: Interesting question. I guess encryption or hiding/storing any sensitive code elsewhere, but again, that probably breaks the contract.

Comment: @STT, you can get around that (in the spirit of the licenses, imo) by simply offering links to the original sources.

Comment: Need more info on the scenario. Do you release the code to the user's server or does the user get access to your server? The problem can be solved either through obfuscation, or through POSIX access management (simply deny access to folders not related to the MVC area of CI).

Comment: Why do you care if other users edit the code? It's their problem. Can you explain more about the product and situation?

Comment: @all I am looking for some kind of encryption technique, that will work just as normal PHP code do but will be in encrypted format.

Comment: @DevZer0 Zend Guard will encode the code. Does it also decodes it?

Comment: @V15HMAY one way encode, you need Zend Guard Loader (for PHP 5.3 and 5.4) or Zend Optimizer (for PHP 5.2 and earlier), to run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server him with encrypted code: something look like this.

```
 Before encode

<?php

  echo "Hello World";

?>
```

After encoded

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KNWNoMiAiSDVsbDIgVzJybGQiOw0KPz4=';
eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLC
cxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GS
UxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

Comment: How did you encoded the code?

Comment: @V15HMAY search for encrypt php code online  you will many result some are freely available and some are payable.

Comment: This is not encryption, its obfuscation. Please don't use word encryption lightly

Comment: @DevZer0 ok its encoded .please suggest the right things to us..

Comment: I will only use this to sell a `Hello World` program :)